# Array is not merging

Tags: php, arrays

```
$array = array(
    "Skill" => "Attack",
    "Current" => 11,
    "Target" => 22
);

$arraytwo = array(
    "Skill" => "Defence",
    "Current" => 66,
    "Target" => 129
);

$array = array_merge($array, $arraytwo);

print_r($array);
```

The output becomes `Array ( [Skill] => Defence [Current] => 66 [Target] => 129 )`

All I simply want to do is merge multiple arrays with the same name in a multi-dimensional array

Comment: Can you show what output you want.

Comment: array_merge is doing exactly what it is supposed to do, so what exactly is your expected outcome for the output array?

Comment: You're getting expected results. Documentation says: "If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the later value for that key will overwrite the previous one. If, however, the arrays contain numeric keys, the later value will not overwrite the original value, but will be appended."

Comment: I want to create a multi-dimensional array and push multiple arrays with the same keys

Answer (score 4):

What you want to use is `array_merge_recursive` instead, it will accomplish exactly what you are looking for. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php

> array_merge_recursive() merges the elements of one or more arrays
>   together so that the values of one are appended to the end of the
>   previous one. It returns the resulting array.
>
> If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the values for
>   these keys are merged together into an array, and this is done
>   recursively, so that if one of the values is an array itself, the
>   function will merge it with a corresponding entry in another array
>   too. If, however, the arrays have the same numeric key, the later
>   value will not overwrite the original value, but will be appended.

```
$array = array(
    "Skill" => "Attack",
    "Current" => 11,
    "Target" => 22
);

$arraytwo = array(
    "Skill" => "Defence",
    "Current" => 66,
    "Target" => 129
);
$result = array_merge_recursive($array, $arraytwo);
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 3):

> If you really want to make a multidimensional array then no need to use array_merge function. You simply use **array()** language construct and pass as many arrays as you want. Look at the below code.

```
$array = array(
    "Skill" => "Attack",
    "Current" => 11,
    "Target" => 22
);

$arraytwo = array(
    "Skill" => "Defence",
    "Current" => 66,
    "Target" => 129
);

$array = array($array, $arraytwo);

print_r($array);
```

**Your output will be as below.**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Skill] => Attack
            [Current] => 11
            [Target] => 22
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Skill] => Defence
            [Current] => 66
            [Target] => 129
        )

)
```